# asp.net visibility of button depended on DataTable row value

Tags: asp.net, button, datatable, visibility

I would like to add button to ListView only for some of rows. I have something like "online chat" and I want to add delete option only for one user. It is complicated because I would like to have "delete" button only in rows which are these user's messages. Messages are saved in DataBase.

.aspx

```
  <td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Visible = <%# Eval("BUTTON") %>
```

.aspx.cs

```
  DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn("BUTTON", typeof(bool));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(newColumn);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (row["USER_NAME"].ToString() == "Franek")
                row["BUTTON"] = true;
            else
            {
                row["BUTTON"] = false;
            }
        }

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        MessagesView.DataSource = dataTable;
        MessagesView.DataBind();
```

[Communicat of error is (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzdhJ.png)

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the column `BUTTON` after `sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);`.

`sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);` would fill the `Data Table`  from Database and it may be resetting the values of "BUTTON" column.

```
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn("BUTTON", typeof(bool));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(newColumn);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (row["USER_NAME"].ToString() == "Franek")
                row["BUTTON"] = true;
            else
            {
                row["BUTTON"] = false;
            }
        }

        MessagesView.DataSource = dataTable;
        MessagesView.DataBind();
```